# prize verb form as intransitive

Tags: transitivity

here's part of an article (http://econ.st/2AASyWO):

> In particular, many in the provinces do not speak Tagalog, the national language, let alone English, which employers prize (the country has eight main languages and dozens of local dialects).

I thought the verb form of "prize" is transitive and has to be used before a noun but here it doesn't seem to be the same with what I know? Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "prize" is transitive.   It has an object.   However, the object precedes the subject in this clause.

Employers prize English.

The clause in question has the subject "employers", the verb "prize" and the direct object "which".   This "which" is a relative pronoun, which not only serves as the transitive verb's direct object but also serves to attach this clause as a non-restrictive modifier to the word that it follows.